# Android : Logout of Facebook from another Activity

Tags: android, facebook, preferences, logout

I am creating an application in which the user can register in different ways , one of which is with Facebook . The Facebook login functioning properly but when I want to logout does nothing. The logout button I want it in another Activity.
1. When I start the application displays an Activity in which there is a button to register.
2. If the user is logged properly an Activity menu is displayed .
3. In the menu there is a button that opens a User Activity information , this is where I want to put my logout button .
4. Once the user logout want you to send me back to the initial Actity (where the login button is ) .
5. I wish that were removed or reset preferences, because if I'm registered properly does not ask me the record and go directly to the menu.

This is the code I use :

public class FacebookLogin extends ActionBarActivity {

```
//
SharedPreferences pref;
//

// Your Facebook APP ID
private static String APP_ID = "94032093……."; // 

// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

// Buttons
ImageView btnFbLogin;
Button Logout;

TextView txttest;
SharedPreferences pref_2;

String nun_2, name_2, email_2;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choose_register);

    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    btnFbLogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogFacebook);
    Logout= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    pref=getSharedPreferences("bus",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //

    //
    txttest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttest);

     pref_2=getSharedPreferences("facebook",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //

    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);


    /**
     * Login button
     * */
    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });

    //I WANT MY LOGOUT BUTTON LIKE THIS

    Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            logoutToFacebook();
        }
    });

            if(pref.contains("num")==true ||pref_2.contains("num_2")==true){

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(FacebookLogin.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
    }

    else{
        if(isNetworkAvailable()){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome... Login please",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }   

}




}

/**
 * Login facebook
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void loginToFacebook() {


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wait a moment please...",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("face",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);  

        //i f is loged star 
        Intent menu = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(menu);            
        finish();

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();


                        //save preferences to login 
                        txttest.setText("Bus");
                        txttest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        getProfileInformation();

                        if(pref_2.contains("num_2")==false){
                            if(txttest.getText().toString().matches("Bus")){

                                num_2=txttest.getText().toString();
                                Editor editor2 = pref_2.edit();
                                editor2.putString("num_2", num_2);

                                editor2.commit();
                                num_2=pref_2.getString("num_2", null);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        //end preferences 



                        Intent menu = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this, Menu.class);
                        startActivity(menu);
                        finish();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


/**
 * user info
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                // Facebook Profile JSON data
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");

                name_2 = name.toString();
                Editor editor = pref_2.edit();
                editor.putString("name_2", name_2);

                editor.commit();
                name_2 = pref_2.getString("name_2", null);  

                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email");

                email_2 = email.toString();
                Editor editor2 = pref_2.edit();
                editor2.putString("email_2", email_2);

                editor2.commit();
                email_2 = pref_2.getString("email_2", null);    



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}

 Public static void logoutToFacebook (){
//HERE I WANT TO WRITE MY LOGOUT CODE AND CALL FROM ANOTHER ACTIVITY (PROFILE ACTIVITY). 
}
```

}

Comment: If someone suggests me this code:
public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     if (session != null) {

         if (!session.isClosed()) {
             session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
             //clear your preferences if saved
         }

     } else {

         session = new Session(context);
         Session.setActiveSession(session);

         session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
             //clear your preferences if saved

     }

 }
Please tell me what I invoke my method logoutToFacebook () ;

Answer (score 5):

In new Facebook SDK 4.0 you should be call to:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Don't forget to call to `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` before you ask any methods in Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I initialize facebook in the Application
 `public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}`
and in another class call

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```